# Очистка таблицы mysql по заданному интервалу

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Каким образом можно реализовать удаление всех строк таблицы бд с заданным интервалом времени, допустим раз в 10 минут?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Включить [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html). Создать event на требуемую операцию с нужной периодичностью.

Comment: С  Event Scheduler  хороший вариант, спасибо, но  mysql  не дает его включить, скачала говорит что нет SUPER  привелегий, потом пытаюсь зайти во вкладку привелегий, выдает, что недостаточно прав для просмотра пользователей. Пытался через консоль "GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'" Выдает ошибку 1045

Comment: Вообще-то если планировщик выключен, но принято решение его использовать - то его следует включить соответствующей корректировкой .INI файла (или комстроки запуска), см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler. Далее - для создания задания необходимо право EVENT, см. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event Ну и само собой текущая учётная запись должна иметь необходимые привилегии для выполнения собственно скрипта эвента. Сообщение же про супера - следствие попытки сделать "по наитию", не читая документации.

Answer (score -1):

самый простой вариант - crontab
например, добавить такую строчку:

```
*/10 * * * * echo "TRUNCATE TABLE db1.table_name;" | mysql -u user --host host --port 9999 database_name
```

можете описать зачем Вам это нужно? возможно, Вам стоить использовать другую базу данных.

Comment: Для использования внешних утилит, когда есть с тем же функционалом, но внутренние - необходимо серьёзное обоснование.

Comment: Event Scheduler лучше! я с Вами согласен. мне кажется, что автору не нужно будет ни то, ни другое

Comment: Согласен, что формулировка вопроса далека от идеальной. Но если товарищ желает выстрелить себе в ногу, надо ли ему мешать?